# IniRead array and pass to download function with progress bar

Tags: autoit

so i'm trying to work out how to get a downloader function working in a tool i'm working on, basically theres a tab with 3 download buttons, based on what button is clicked in the tab i'd like it to pass to one function, the downloder that will read the links from the ini file, with a progress bar in the tab I'll post the code bellow so you'll get an understanding

So it will download the files absolutely fine the only problem is when I start the app the download for the first file in the array starts automatically even though I didn't click the label in the tab, nor does the rest of the GUI function, I can't switch tabs as it just "freezes" then the download starts all over again if i comment out the case dwitch for $modlabel1 like so ";Case $modlabel1" it allows me to switch tabs etc just fine and I can switch tabs and click on the other 2 buttons and they will download as intended but the GUI stays on the mod tab till its finished, another small issue I have is i need the files to download with the same as the source file name, is that possible to do with InetGet?

Downloads Tab

```
Func _mods_gui()
    $modsgui = GUICreate("Mods", 1270, 610, 5, 105, BitOR($ws_popup, $ws_border), $ws_ex_mdichild, $maingui)
    GUISetBkColor(3487029)
    DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "AnimateWindow", "hwnd", $setgui, "int", 250, "long", 524288)
    $progressbar1 = GUICtrlCreateProgress(10, 200, 1250, 50, $PBS_MARQUEE)
    $modlabel1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Download" & @CRLF & "DayZ Epoch 1.0.5.1", 50, 50, 350, 100, $ss_center)
    GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 30, 700, 0, "Segeo UI", 4)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 3825)
    GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 16777215)
    _guictrl_setonhover(-1, "_Hover", "_Hover_Leave")
    $modlabel2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Download" & @CRLF & "DayZ Overwatch 0.2.5", 450, 50, 350, 100, $ss_center)
    GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 30, 700, 0, "Segeo UI", 4)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 3825)
    GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 16777215)
    _guictrl_setonhover(-1, "_Hover", "_Hover_Leave")
    $modlabel3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Download" & @CRLF & "Namalsk 0.75", 850, 50, 350, 100, $ss_center)
    GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 30, 700, 0, "Segeo UI", 4)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 3825)
    GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 16777215)
    _guictrl_setonhover(-1, "_Hover", "_Hover_Leave")
    $modsgr2 = GUICtrlCreateGraphic(0, 25, 1270, 250)
    GUICtrlSetState(-1, $gui_disable)
    GUICtrlSetGraphic(-1, $gui_gr_color, 0, 2368548)
    GUICtrlSetGraphic(-1, $gui_gr_rect, 0, 0, 1270, 250)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $modsgui)
EndFunc
```

While Switch Case

```
Case $modsgui
    Switch $nmsg[0]
        Case $modlabel1
            _downloadmod(0)
        Case $modlabel2
            _downloadmod(1)
        Case $modlabel3
            _downloadmod(2)
    EndSwitch
```

Download Array

```
Func _downloadmod($mod)
    $modarrayread[3] = [IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\LauncherFiles\data\XGLConfig.cfg", "mod_links", "mod_epoch", Default), IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\LauncherFiles\data\XGLConfig.cfg", "mod_links", "mod_overwatch", Default), IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\LauncherFiles\data\XGLConfig.cfg", "mod_links", "mod_namalsk", Default)]
    $dwnmod = InetGet($modarrayread[$mod], @ScriptDir & "\Mods\$name.zip", 1, 1)
    Do
        Sleep(50)
        $prc = Round(InetGetInfo($dwnmod, 0) / (InetGetInfo($dwnmod, 1)) * 100)
        GUICtrlSetData($progressbar1, $prc)
    Until InetGetInfo($dwnmod, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
EndFunc
```

INI

```
[mod_links]
mod_epoch=http://files.xexgaming.com/mods/@DayZ_Epoch1051.zip
mod_overwatch=http://files.xexgaming.com/mods/@DayZOverwatch.zip
mod_namalsk=http://files.xexgaming.com/mods/@Namalsk.zip
```

Credits to Trojan for the help with the array, worked out how to get the parameters using his example

Comment: Anyone else got any input on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the example script in the help for GUICtrlCreateProgress as base and wrote a script which hopefully does what u wanted it to do.
If you have any questions feel free to ask :)

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <ProgressConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <InetConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    Local $progressbar1, $button1, $button2, $button3
    Local $downarrayread[3] = [IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\Files\data\Config.cfg", "links", "link_1", Default), IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\Files\data\Config.cfg", "links", "link_2", Default), IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\Files\data\Config.cfg", "links", "link_3", Default)]
    GUICreate("Downloads", 220, 100, 100, 200)
    $progressbar1 = GUICtrlCreateProgress(10, 40, 200, 20, $PBS_SMOOTH)
    $button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start 1", 5, 70, 70, 20)
    $button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start 2", 75, 70, 70, 20)
    $button3 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start 3", 145, 70, 70, 20)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)



    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                ExitLoop
            Case $button1
                $hDownload = InetGet($downarrayread[1], @ScriptDir & "/Downloads/File1", $INET_FORCERELOAD, $INET_DOWNLOADBACKGROUND)
                Do
                    Sleep(250)
                    GUICtrlSetData($progressbar1,((InetGetInfo($hDownload,$INET_DOWNLOADSIZE )/InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADREAD))*100)/3)
                Until InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
            Case $button2
                $hDownload = InetGet($downarrayread[2], @ScriptDir & "/Downloads/File2", $INET_FORCERELOAD, $INET_DOWNLOADBACKGROUND)
                Do
                    Sleep(250)
                    GUICtrlSetData($progressbar1,((InetGetInfo($hDownload,$INET_DOWNLOADSIZE )/InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADREAD))*100)/3+33.33)
                Until InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
            Case $button3
                $hDownload = InetGet($downarrayread[3], @ScriptDir & "/Downloads/File3", $INET_FORCERELOAD, $INET_DOWNLOADBACKGROUND)
                Do
                    Sleep(250)
                    GUICtrlSetData($progressbar1,((InetGetInfo($hDownload,$INET_DOWNLOADSIZE )/InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADREAD))*100)/3+66.66)
                Until InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
        EndSwitch
    WEnd

EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look, is this to be all done in one function? That makes things easier I guess than having 2 separate ones :D I'll implement this and see how it goes :D thanks!

Comment: Of course you can just remove the _Example()_, _Func Example()_ and _EndFunc_ and it will do the same.

Comment: Is there a max file size InteGet can do or download speed? It just seems to hang, I have 60Mb download speed and can download files of 2GB quick but the bar doesn't seem to move at all, I've literally just copied this code into a au3 to try it out before hand and also, pushing button 3 thows and error and closes the app, still learning here :P

Array variable has incorrect number of subscripts or subscript dimension range exceeded.:
$hDownload = InetGet($downarrayread[3], @ScriptDir & "/Mods/", $INET_FORCERELOAD, $INET_DOWNLOADBACKGROUND)
$hDownload = InetGet(^ ERROR

Comment: Got it! its downloading now, but button 3 still causes a crash :/

Comment: Problem solved, had to change the InetGet($downarrayread[1] lines to

InetGet($downarrayread[0]
InetGet($downarrayread[1]
InetGet($downarrayread[2]

Comment: Hmm, so upon trying to implement this it breaks my While statement for my GUI's tabs, is it possibly to get the downloading dealt with by one function, I.E $button1 clicked, pass parameter into _download(), function downloads said file, then back in the GUI they decide they want to download a different file using button2 so button 2 pressed then that passes into the download function again and the download function goes, okay start download, but i'd still like the progress bar in the GUI tab either that or a popout

Comment: Updated OP with new results

Comment: Sorry didn't have much time but it looks like u figured it out by yourself :)

Comment: I'm still having one small issue in the updated OP if you have another contact i'm happy to send you the source code to look at in its entirety to see if you can help me out seeing everything